# GDB failed to debug android-native-c-program in asm?

Tags: android, assembly, gdb, arm

I want to use gdb to debug a helloworld c program in android, by this tutorial:
http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/debugging_gdb.html

The arm-eabi-gdb, runs my helloworld successfully without breakpoint, but when I put some breakpoints and run it by 'ni' or 'si', it is said that "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." I really cannot understand...

That's my steps:
**1 testmain.c & Android.mk(in cm_gingerbread/development/test2/)**

```
// testmain.c
#include <stdio.h>
void myfn() {
  printf("okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk...\n");
}
int main() {
  myfn();
  return 0;
}

// Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := testmain
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := testmain.c
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

**2 compiling**

```
  neil@vm64:~/dev/cm_gingerbread/development/test2$ mm  
  target thumb C: testmain <= development/test2/testmain.c  
  target Executable: testmain  (out/target/product/bravo/obj/EXECUTABLES/testmain_intermediates/LINKED/testmain)  
  target Non-prelinked: testmain (out/target/product/bravo/symbols/system/bin/testmain)  
  target Strip: testmain   (out/target/product/bravo/obj/EXECUTABLES/testmain_intermediates/testmain)
  Install: out/target/product/bravo/system/bin/testmain
```

**3 push & run**

```
  neil@vm64:~$ adb push ~/dev/cm_gingerbread/out/target/product/bravo/system/bin/testmain /system/bin  
  neil@vm64:~$ adb shell  
  # cd system/bin  
  # chmod a+x testmain  
  # ./testmain  
  okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk...
```

**4 run gdbserver**

```
  neil@vm64:~$ adb shell  
  # gdbserver :5039 /system/bin/testmain  
  Process /system/bin/testmain created; pid = 2862  
  Listening on port 5039
```

**5 run gdbclient**

```
  neil@vm64:~/dev/cm_gingerbread$ adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039  
  neil@vm64:~/dev/cm_gingerbread$ prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gdb ~/dev/cm_gingerbread/out/target/product/bravo/symbols/system/bin/testmain  
  (gdb) set solib-absolute-prefix   /home/neil/dev/cm_gingerbread/out/target/product/bravo/symbols  
  (gdb) set solib-search-path /home/neil/dev/cm_gingerbread/out/target/product/bravo/symbols/system/lib  
  (gdb) target remote :5039  
  (gdb) x/10i 0x8430  
     0x8430 <myfn>:       ldr     r0, [pc, #8]    ; (0x843c <myfn+12>)  
     0x8432 <myfn+2>:     push    {r4, lr}  
     0x8434 <myfn+4>:     add     r0, pc  
     0x8436 <myfn+6>:     blx     0x83f0  
     0x843a <myfn+10>:    pop     {r4, pc}  
     ...  
  (gdb) b *0x8436  
     Breakpoint 1 at 0x8436: file development/test2/testmain.c, line 4.  
  (gdb) b *0x83f0  
     Breakpoint 2 at 0x83f0  
  (gdb) c  
     Continuing.  
     Breakpoint 1, 0x00008436 in myfn () at development/test2/testmain.c:4  
  (gdb) ni  
     Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
     0x000083f8 in ?? ()
```

And when I just run it by 'c' command without any breakpoint, it's OK:

```
(gdb) target remote :5039
  Remote debugging using :5039
  warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
  GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
  and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
  0xb0001000 in ?? ()
(gdb) c
  Continuing.
  Cannot access memory at address 0x0
  Error while mapping shared library sections:
  /system/bin/linker: No such file or directory.
  Error while mapping shared library sections:
  libc.so: No such file or directory.
  ...

  Program exited normally.
```

Comment: Something looks wrong with the dissassembly - it is incrementing two bytes at a time indicating thumb mode, but then it jumps four bytes to the pop instruction.  Maybe you have a buggy gdb.

Comment: Newer thumb instruction sets include 4 Byte instructions, that `blx 0x83f0` looks like one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using wrong gdb/gdbserver combo. I work on AOSP 4.0.3 fork. We ended up building our own gdb using 7.3 version of gdb sources instead of the ones that came prebuilt.

Please check [Debugging Android native apps](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html) article. It talks about some of the issues with native debugging and workarounds for them.

You might want to check [Linaro site for latest gdb/gdbserver](https://releases.linaro.org/13.10/components/toolchain/binaries) binaries.